# can we use order by clause with group by

Tags: sql

Hi
   I am using following query --

```
select * from table_name order by status desc
```

It shows the desired result **with all records**,but as n when i use following query -

```
select * from table_name group by category order by status desc
```

It shows **only 2 records** of distinct category with sorted order.

Is it because i am using order by with group by.....

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Is that what you are looking for rather?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're using `group by`. `Order by` doesn't change the result set itself, but changes the order of rows.

Comment: yep it changes the order of rows but it also minimize the total records.as i have 2 categories from 1st query it shows me 68 records as all but from 2nd query it shows only 2 rows/records.

Comment: @Tiger007: it **doesn't** minimise. Don't you see that 1st and second query differ only with `group by` added? Look one more time at your queries and answer: what have you added to the second query? (and obviously "it" changed the resultset)

Comment: yep dear it changes excatly I agree to ur answer but its not actually the problem is.i don't want 2 use any agreegate function still want the records in following manner.---------NO  Category  Name Staus                      where                   1   Laptops XYZ    Y        like-wise

Comment: @Tiger007: I cannot get what you mean :-S Update your original question with detailed information about what you want.

Comment: c i got 68 records with 'select * from sony_ocmaster order by status desc' dis query which is right... n when i fire 'select * from sony_ocmaster group by category order by status desc' dis query w/o aggregate fun it shows only 2 records so either the query is wrong bcoz im using order by wid group by n without aggregate fun or provide me alternative options

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Often you'll want to use aggregate functions like COUNT() and SUM() with the GROUP BY clause.

For instance count the number of records with the first name Bob.

```
SELECT First_Name, COUNT(First_Name) FROM Users GROUP BY First_Name ORDER BY First_Name ASC;
```

Comment: I agree to ur answer but its not actually the problem is.i don't want 2 use any agreegate function still want the records in following manner.---------NO  Category  Name Staus                      where                   1   Laptops XYZ    Y        like-wise

Answer (score 0):

Yes. "Group by" will aggregate data and group it by the field specified.

And when you use a `group by` you need to include some aggregating function, else it won't work, e.g.

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM [table]
GROUP BY Category
```

Also, an `ORDER BY` is applied on the result set of the query only.

**EDIT:** From your comments it sounds like you are actually trying to "visually group" the records in your result set. If that is indeed the case, then *don't* use `GROUP BY` and just go:

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
ORDER BY Category, Status
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: I agree to ur answer but its not actually the problem is.i don't want 2 use any agreegate function still want the records in following manner.---------NO  Category  Name Staus                      where                   1   Laptops XYZ    Y        like-wise

Comment: "Also, an ORDER BY is applied on the result set of the query, so you can only order on columns you actually emit from the query." --- totally wrong.

Comment: @zerkms: Apologies, I phrased that sentence completely wrong. You are correct. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing, because normally you would only be able to select fields and order by fields that are also in your group by.

MySQL does that differently and allows you in certain cases to order by fields that are not in the group by. These fields (status, in this case) are implicitly added to the group by. So you're actually grouping by category *and* status.

Comment: "allows you in certain cases" --- mysql allows it in all cases ;-)